# How do I specify a fixed-size buffer in C++/CLI?

Tags: c++-cli

In C#, I can specify a [fixed sized buffer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zycewsya.aspx) using the `fixed` keyword, like so:

```
public unsafe struct StructWithFixedBuffer
{
    public fixed char FixedBuffer[128];
}
```

how would I express the same thing in C++/CLI?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

One of the C++/CLI developer blogs had code for a template solution to this, I'll try to find a link.

[Ahh, found it.  It's called `inline_array`.](https://web.archive.org/web/20160126134209/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/branbray/archive/2005/07/20/441099.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

The C# syntax was added as a way to express the C++ syntax you've know forever. :)

```
public:
    wchar_t FixedBuffer[128];
```

Comment: This would result in error C4368 `cannot define 'x' as a member of managed 'typename': mixed types are not supported`

Answer (score 1):

Quote:

> size of the 128 element char array is 256 bytes. Fixed size char buffers always take two bytes per character, regardless of the encoding.

So you want:

```
struct StructWithFixedBuffer
{
    char FixedBuffer[128*2];
};
```

Comment: Pretty sure the requirement is to put the buffer inside a managed type, not a native `struct`.