# C++ Cli [MarshalAs] attribute moment of taking effect?

Tags: struct, c++-cli, marshalling, unmanaged, value-type

if I declare a value Struct in C++ CLI in this way:

```
  [StructLayout(LayoutKind::Sequential, CharSet = CharSet::Ansi, Pack = 2)]
  value struct TEST
  {
  public:
     UInt32 bla;                                 
     UInt32 foo;                                  
     [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType::ByValTStr, SizeConst = 10)]
     String^ somestring;
     UInt32 bar;                   
  };
```

and use that struct, when does the line
   **[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType::ByValTStr, SizeConst = 10)]**
take effect?
Has it only a effect if I call some native function which is declared with dll import or if I do manually marshalling or the whole time?

My question lead to a implementation of a C++ Cli Wrapper for Native C functions for some C# modules in a large project. 
if I do something like this:

```
TEST bla;
pin_ptr<TEST> pinner=&bla;
```

Is it certain, that in that moment after pinning my struct is wrapped together and has a size of 22 Byte (3*4 for the integer and 10 for the string)? Or could the string be bigger?

Comment: Your struct contains a handle to the string.  The `MarshalAs` declaration isn't defining a fixed-length array in either C# or C++/CLI, C# has the `fixed` keyword for that and [there's a library for C++/CLI floating around to do the same thing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2138473/how-do-i-specify-a-fixed-size-buffer-in-c-cli).  Furthermore, `pin_ptr` is unnecessary for stack variables, only data inside the managed heap can move around and therefore needs to be pinned.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it takes effect when you make a call to an unmanaged function that you've declared with the [DllImport] attribute and that function has an argument of type TEST.  Or when you explicitly marshal the structure with Marshal::StructureToPtr or Marshal::PtrToStructure.  It does *not* take effect in your 2nd snippet.  Nor is it necessary to use pin_ptr<> there, the *bla* variable is stored on the stack so doesn't have to be pinned.

This is something you very rarely ever do in C++/CLI.  Since you'd have the unmanaged version of TEST already available from a .h file.  You'd simply create that unmanaged version and copy the members, lots faster than leaving it up to the pinvoke marshaller.  But you can, at least it takes care of the string.  Use Marshal::StructureToPtr().

Comment: Also, I think pin_ptr<> pins the boxed version of the struct here.  A copy, not the original.

Answer (score 0):

I'll answer one part of your question: Using pin_ptr does not cause marshalling to occur.  pin_ptr is locking down the address of the managed object--it is not marshalling it to an unmanaged object.  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1dz8byfh(v=vs.80).aspx for more details.

Comment: ok that was still clear to me but if [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType::ByValTStr, SizeConst = 10)]
has a general effect my struct size and order will be always the same...but I dont know if?

Answer (score 0):

Use a fixed-size buffer instead: [How do I specify a fixed-size buffer in C++/CLI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2138473/how-do-i-specify-a-fixed-size-buffer-in-c-cli)