# C# - fixed/inline arrays

Tags: c#, unsafe

I'm writing a B+-tree implementation in C#, and the tree implementation I chose for my application has a very specific structure which is cache-conscious. To achieve these properties, it has strict layout policies on tree nodes.

What I want is simply expressed using C#'s [fixed](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zycewsya%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) keyword for fixed-sized buffers:

```
public abstract class Tree<K, T> { }
sealed class Node<K, T> : Tree<K, T>
{
    Node<K, T> right;
    fixed Tree<K, T> nodes[127]; // inline array of 128 nodes
}
```

Unfortunately, fixed-sized buffers can only be used with primitive value types, like int and float. Just using plain arrays would add pointer indirections which destroy the cache-friendly properties of this tree type.

I also can't generate 128 fields and use pointer arithmetic to extract the field I want because [there are no conversions between pointer types and managed objects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y31yhkeb.aspx).

About the only thing left is generating 128 fields with an indexer that selects the right one based on a switch (which can't be fast), or writing it as a C library and using P/Invoke, which would also destroy the performance.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Why would C library destroy performance?

Comment: @Dani: It's not the C library, but p/invoke that is the concern, IIUC.

Comment: You will always have a pointer indirection unless you make Tree a struct.  This does *not* imply that an array of objects is not cache-friendly.  The friendly garbage collector ensures it is, it compacts the heap and puts every nicely together.  Avoid premature optimization.  The nodes member should almost certainly be a List<>.

Comment: Thanks for the correction Henk, post updated. Unfortunately there's other data in this tree structure that I excluded for the sake of brevity, but that was good idea. Hans, an array is cache-friendly, but a class pointing to an array is less so. I need the array embedded in the class, or a struct pointing to an array would also work.

Comment: @naasking: The 129th "element" Hans was talking about was `right`.  You probably didn't want to reduce the size of the array, unless you want computations modulo 127 instead of bit-shifting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use C++/CLI.  That gives you total control over layout, just like C, but the cost of managed/unmanaged transitions is much reduced from p/invoke (probably no extra cost at all).

Unfortunately managed code is not very good for "cache-conscious" work: inside the managed heap you are powerless to avoid false-sharing.  C++/CLI lets you use the unmanaged allocator, so you can not only keep the data contiguous, but aligned to cache lines.

---

Also note: Using the `class` keyword creates a "reference type" which already adds that level of indirection you wanted to avoid.  With some reorganization, you might be able to use a `struct` and an array and not have any more indirection that the code you proposed.

Comment: I already tried just using structs with a managed array. Unfortunately, because there are more than 1 tree node type, the array must be polymorphic and thus a pointer type of some sort. I don't know much about C++/CLI, so I'll take a look. If it would allow me to specify a reference type with an inline array without marshalling overhead of P/Invoke, then I'm sold.

Comment: @naasking: C++/CLI isn't going to change the rules for managed types (well, you can try: see [How do I specify a fixed-size buffer in C++/CLI?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2138473/how-do-i-specify-a-fixed-size-buffer-in-c-cli/4988720#4988720) )  Mainly, it's going to get you to "C library with p/invoke" without needing the p/invoke part.  "C++ interop" (codename "It Just Works") is both faster than p/invoke and understands C header files so you don't have to write p/invoke declarations.

Comment: Ultimately, you want to use unmanaged structures with explicit alignment if you care about cache behavior.  In this case, that'll be a native C++ struct containing an array of pointers.

Comment: I was hopeful for a minute there, but that inline_array template has roughly the same restrictions as 'fixed', ie. T can only be a value type. Darn.

Comment: @naasking: You can make an array of pointers though, and use the `gcroot` template to store handles back to managed objects.

Comment: Ah, wasn't even aware of gcroot. Seems it's a wrapper for GCHandle. I think I see how I can do this in C# now, although it involves casting which will hurt the cache performance. Assuming C++\CLI doesn't perform the type testing+casting behind the scenes, gcroot and auto_gcroot look like a viable solution. Thanks Ben!

Comment: @naasking: The path it sounds like you're taking.... yes you'll get a fixed-size buffer of references to objects, but I expect performance to get worse, due to GCHandle.  What I'm suggesting is to use standard C++ classes to implement the tree, and just use `gcroot` in the leaves, where you need to get back the handle to a managed object.  Or is the array all leaves anyway (i.e. you'll never store a `Node<K,T>` inside `nodes`)?