# Porting a C++ class to a ref class (unmanaged to managed)

Tags: c++, c++-cli, unmanaged, managed

I have an unmanaged class, which I'm calling from a C++ Windows Form (managed class). However, I would like to re-write this class as a ref class, but I'm not sure how to deal with global array members that are declared within the unmanaged class.

As an example I wrote a very simple class, that shows somehow what I need to do.

```
public class test {

private:
    int myArray[5][24]; 

public:
int assign(int i){
    test::myArray[2][4] = i;
    return 0;
}

int dosomething(int i){
    return test::myArray[2][4] + i;
}
```

In here I have a global member array, which I want to be able to access from all the functions within the class.

In the windows form I have a button and a combo box. This way when the button is pressed it just calls the functions in the class and displays the results.

```
private: System::Void thumbButton_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {

    test my_class;

    my_class.assign(5);
comboBox1->Text = my_class.dosomething(6).ToString();
}
```

Now if I try to change the class to a ref class, there is an error because of the global array being unmanaged. I tried doing this with std::vectors, which is a better approach than using the array directly, but get the same error. Therefore, I would really appreciate if someone can point me to a way to rewrite this class as a ref class. Thank you!

Comment: This syntax is pure nonsense, enough to make it hard to understand what you're getting at in the first place.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I specify a fixed-size buffer in C++/CLI?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2138473/how-do-i-specify-a-fixed-size-buffer-in-c-cli)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think 'global' is the right word for your unmanaged array, as it is contained within the unmanaged class definition. The unmanaged array doesn't have the `static` keyword either, so it's an instance variable, which is nowhere near global.

Regardless, it seems the issue you're having is with the array definition. `int myArray[5][24]` is an unmanaged 'object', which can't be directly included in your managed class. (You can have pointers to unmanaged objects, but not inline unmanaged objects.) You could switch that to a pointer to an integer array, and deal with malloc & free, but it's much simpler to go with a managed array instead.

Here's the syntax to declare that array as managed:

```
public ref class test
{
private:
    array<int, 2>^ myArray;

public:
    test()
    {
        this->myArray = gcnew array<int, 2>(5, 24);
    }

    int assign(int i)
    {
        this->myArray[2,4] = i;
        return 0;
    }

    int dosomething(int i)
    {
        return this->myArray[2,4] + i;
    }
};
```

The array class is templated on the data type and the number of dimensions, so for a 2D array of integers, `array<int, 2>` is what you want.